# Emacs equivalent of vim's vertsplit (vs)?

Tags: vim, emacs

When I have a single file open, I want to open another, with the window split vertically. In vim, this is `:vs filename`. In emacs, I think this is `C-X 3`, `C-X o`, `C-X C-F`, `filename`. Can we make this shorter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`C-h f find-file-other-window RET`

It is bound to `C-x 4 f` by default, but you can remap it to `C-x f` with `global-set-key`.

Comment: The help page for `find-file` should maybe mention the related function. Otherwise, remember that `C-h f find--file TAB TAB` will autocomplete to all possible matches and makes it easy to look for something related to those words.

Answer (score 0):

I think using just `find-file-other-window` is not exactly what you want. It uses `display-buffer`, which is not just splitting vertically, but tries to find a place to show new buffer. You can do something like this

```
(defun find-file-split-horizontally()
  (interactive)
  (flet                                 ; temporary change
                                        ; display-buffer function to
                                        ; our needs
    ((display-buffer (buffer-or-name &optional not-this-window frame)
       (select-window (split-window-horizontally)) ; select newly created window
       (switch-to-buffer buffer-or-name)))
(call-interactively 'find-file-other-window)))

(defun switch-to-buffer-split-horizontally()
  (interactive)
  (flet
    ((display-buffer (buffer-or-name &optional not-this-window frame)
       (select-window (split-window-horizontally))
       (switch-to-buffer buffer-or-name)))
(call-interactively
  ;; use only one of these
  'ido-switch-buffer-other-window
  ;;'switch-to-buffer-other-window
  )))
```

This will always try to split your current buffer horizontally.